# CMakeLists.txt: How to print a message if ctest fails?

Tags: cmake, ctest

Is there a way I can setup CMakeLists.txt to print a message if `ctest` tests fail? For example:

```
cmake ..
make
ctest // fails
message output: Please contact xyz@mail.com to resolve testing problems.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677077 for a more elaborate version of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [message](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html]), which can help you output information to the configuration log process.

Comment: That does not output message in ctest or make test right?

Comment: oh, you mean as target? If so...then you'll need to go deaper with [CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/ctest.html). The link points you about the current features. As a sidenote, you can create a custom target and grab its exits status without ctest.

Comment: Yes, I looked at it but couldn't figure out myself, I was hoping someone can give me an example.